# VIM Colemak yank remapping issues

Tags: vim, yank, colemak

So I am using an alternate Keyboard layout on my Mac (Colemak) and I have vim remapped for colemak layout by editing the `.vimrc` file as such (just two lines so that you get the picture):

```
noremap y o  
noremap p r
... (and so on)
```

So now, in VIM when hitting the <kbd>L</kbd> key (on QWERTY layout) resembles <kbd>I</kbd> on colemak, it opens the Insert mode as it should. However, when I hit <kbd>y y</kbd> to yank a line, it instead executes <kbd>y</kbd> and then <kbd>o</kbd>. Do I need to remap <kbd>y y</kbd> to <kbd>o</kbd> now?

```
:map o yy
```

But that would mean that in editing mode an <kbd>o</kbd> would turn out <kbd>y y</kbd>, wouldn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong and help me to solve this quirk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somewhere in your `.vimrc` file your `y -> o` mapping is made to only apply for [operator-pending mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/intro.html#Operator-pending), since from what you wrote your first <kbd>y</kbd> registers as <kbd>y</kbd>.

You can work around this in a few ways:

1. [*Unmap*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:ounmap) the key for operator mode only:

   ```
   :ounmap y
   ```
2. Map `o -> yy` to [*only normal mode*](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:nnoremap) (so it won't affect your editing):

   ```
   :nnoremap o yy
   ```
3. Just use Vim's native mapping for <kbd>Y</kbd> (or the Colemak equivalent of <kbd>Y</kbd>) to yank the entire line.

Comment: Also see langmap and keymap, which makes these things much more natural...